# Jquery Show Popup only when window is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

I am trying to display a confirmation message when the user **closes the browser/tab** and **not when any of the links on page is clicked.**

I have got the first part of displaying the message on window close working nicely but problem is that the message/alert is **displayed also when user clicks on any link on the page.**

I have got code from somewhere to prevent this behavior but still when ever any link is clicked the alert pops up.

Here is the code:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>                         
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/backfix-min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e){
            $("#lead-gen-modal").dialog("open");
            // This line only appears in alert boxes for IE
            return "Wait\! Don\'t Go\! We have a special offer for you\. Stay on this page to receive big savings\!";   
    }); 

    $("a").click(function() {
        window.onbeforeunload=null;
    });         
});
```

Answer (score 1):

just use a global variable
and set it to `false` when clicking a link.

```
var key = true;
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e){
  if(key)
  $("#lead-gen-modal").dialog("open");
});
```

update :

```
 $(document).on("click","a",function() {
      key=false; 
 });
```

or if you just want to prevent closing window you can do this :

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
   if(key)
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer damon problem is I am really new to JS and don't know how to do that.

Comment: This code only works if you click on link before closing the window. If you choose to stay on the page then no link on the page works.

Comment: Works OK unless the user is opening a new tab (i.e. shift clicking), in which case `key` gets set to false permanently and the user hasn't left the page yet.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for something like this.

```
$(window).unload(function() {
  alert("bye");
});
```

If that does not work on Chrome try this

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
  return "bye";
});
```

jQuery API: unload() http://api.jquery.com/unload/

Comment: I mentioned clearly in my question that. I have got the alert part working. Only thing that needs to be fixed is message SHOULD NOT be displayed when any other link on the page is clicked

Comment: That should not trigger when any link is clicked remove the click event on the "a" tag and run the function as you would otherwise. You have your alert message contained in a function that is triggered when a link is clicked, so your purposely doing exactly what you don't want to do.

Comment: I used it just now and it has same effect as my code. It triggers on link click as well