# Show form before closing site several tabs issue

Tags: jquery, cookies

I want to display form, before closing site.

I have found a solution by damon [Jquery Show Popup only when window is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26484767/jquery-show-popup-only-when-window-is-closed)

```
var key = true;
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e){
  if(key)
  $("#lead-gen-modal").dialog("open");
});
```

and fix for document links

```
 $(document).on("click","a",function() {
      key=false; 
 });
```

Good solution, thanks damon.

**BUT**

There is another question. For example user opens links in new tab. For example He opens several tabs in browser with pages of my site. And closing every tab he will get a form, before closing. It is not exactly what i want.

May be solution of this is in cookies? For example first visit site - set cookie that the `page is first`, another tabs set cookie `secondary` , and open form only if cookie is `first page`? Is it correct or there is another solution?

Comment: what exactly unclear?

Comment: Stackoverflow users become very nervous...simple question, i want to find way to fix problem, instead of answer i have dislike...ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a cookie or `localStorage` to add a counter to it everytime a new tab/window opens:

```
$(window).load(function() {
   // check if counter exists
   var counter = localStorage.getItem('tabCounter');

   // if not, create it
   if(counter == null) {
      counter = 0;
   }
   else {
      counter = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('tabCounter'));
   }

   // increment
   counter = counter + 1;

   // save new value
   localStorage.setItem('tabCounter', counter);
});
```

now on unload you can do the following:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e){
   // get counter
   var counter = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('tabCounter'));

   // decrement
   counter = counter - 1;

   // save new value
   localStorage.setItem('tabCounter', counter);

   // if this is the last tab
   if(counter == 0) {
      $("#lead-gen-modal").dialog("open");
   }

});
```

Comment: Thanks, Ted, there are still kind people on stackoverflow

Comment: As soon as possible.